# Shutdown PC after remmina connection closed

Tags: debian, command-line, scripting, shutdown, remmina

I'd like my PC to shutdown straight after I close my remmina remote connection. I searched for solutions but remmina itself shows abnormal behavior.

```
someprogram && sudo shutdown -h 0
```

Running this command works, and the PC shuts down after closing someprogram.
However, it only works because someprogram halts the terminal session until it is closed. After which sudo shutdown can execute

```
remmina -c path/to/connection/file && sudo shutdown -h 0
```

Running this command shuts down the PC straight away since remmina doest halt the terminal session. I'd like remmina to have the same behavior as the someprogramm. Is it somehow doable to get remmina to halt the session?

Example:

```
firefox && sudo shutdown -h 0
```

PC shuts down after Firefox is closed.

```
remmina && sudo shutdown -h 0
```

PC shuts down straight away.

Comment: the first remmina to start (probably automatically at GUI login) stays "resident". Next to run will just detect remmina is running and hand off the work to the running one. That's why it won't wait. + several variations about this (don't stop when last window is closed etc.) makes what you want impractical. Same would happen if firefox was already running when you type "firefox" again

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [FreeRDP Remmina Wiki's User's Guide](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Remmina-User's-guide).

[image: ss#1]